# RxJS Ajax how to get response cookie

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, rxjs

When I make an RxJS Ajax call request I set the headers of request, but how can i get Cookie of RxJS Ajax Response?

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
ajax({
    url: "some url",
    body: {
        parameter1: "abc",
        parameter2: "def"
    },
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    },
    method: 'POST',
    responseType: 'json'
})
.subscribe(
    payLoad => {
        console.log(payLoad);
        console.log(payLoad.headers);
    },
    error => console.log(error),
    () => console.log( 'done' )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `withCredentials: true` to set [appropriate XHR option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) so that cookies & headers will be treated differently.

And then, after request is done, access cookie using [document.cookie](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) or [some other library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

something like:

```
ajax("https://some-url").subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(document.cookie);
  }
);
```